# (flutter) why does a component not disappear?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a biginner in Flutter.
I am practicing to make a game like Temple Run or Flight to fight Game, moving a player to avoid or get something that is coming (I made the class for it named star.)
I try to make a code when a player and a star collide, a star disappears and the score gets higher.
My problem is, when a player and a star collide, the star doesn't disappear, but just passes through the player.
Can you please check the problem? Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flame/collisions.dart';


class GamePlay extends StatelessWidget {
  const GamePlay ({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GameWidget(
        game: RacingGame(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Player extends RectangleComponent with CollisionCallbacks {
  static const playerSize = 96.0;
  Player({required position})
      : super(
    position: position,
    size: Vector2.all(playerSize),
    anchor: Anchor.bottomCenter,
  );
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    add(RectangleHitbox());
  }
}

class RacingGame extends FlameGame with TapCallbacks {
  late Player player;
  double nextSpawnSeconds = 0.0;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    player = Player(
      position: Vector2(size.x * 0.25, size.y - 20),
    );
    add(player);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    super.onTapDown(event);
    if (!event.handled) {
      final touchPoint = event.canvasPosition;
      if (touchPoint.x > size.x / 2) {
        player.position = Vector2(size.x * 0.75, size.y - 20);
      } else {
        player.position = Vector2(size.x * 0.25, size.y - 20);
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  void update(dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    nextSpawnSeconds -= dt;
    if (nextSpawnSeconds < 0) {
      add(Star(Vector2(size.x * (Random().nextInt(10) > 5 ? 0.75 : 0.25), 0)));
      nextSpawnSeconds = 0.3 + Random().nextDouble() * 2;
    }
  }
}

class Star extends RectangleComponent with HasGameRef, CollisionCallbacks {
  static const starSize = 64.0;

  Star(position)
      : super(
    position: position,
    size: Vector2.all(starSize),
    anchor: Anchor.bottomCenter,
  );

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    paint.color = Colors.yellow;
    add(RectangleHitbox());
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    position.y = position.y + 5;
    if ( position.y - size.y > gameRef.size.y ) {
      removeFromParent();
    }
  }
  @override
  bool onComponentTypeCheck(PositionComponent other) {
    if (other is Star) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return super.onComponentTypeCheck(other);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onCollisionStart(
      Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints,
      PositionComponent other,
      ) {
    if (other is Player) {
      removeFromParent();
    } else {
      super.onCollisionStart(intersectionPoints, other);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and for anyone who's in trouble with the similar problem:
I added `HasCollisionDetection` in the definition of class RacingGame.

```
class RacingGame extends FlameGame with TapCallbacks, **HasCollisionDetection**
```